# WSO2 Identity Server [Configuración de secretos en Deployment.toml]

Tags: wso2

Espero que mi descripción de como hacer funcionar los secretos en la configuración de WSO2-IS le ayude.

El problema que me encontré en muchos foros es que las personas que intentan configurar los secretos en WSO2-IS no consiguen que dichos secretos se descifren en tiempo de ejecución.

En mi caso estoy utilizando la versión 5.11.0 en una imagen docker con kubernetes, aunque creo que la configuración es igualmente válida para instalaciones tradicionales.

1. **Activar "*secure vault*" en fichero "*deployment.toml*"**:
   Para activarlo se require incluir en la etiqueta "*[server]*" la propiedad
   "*enable_secure_vault=true*".

quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
[server]
enable_secure_vault=true
```

2. **Configuración de "*ciphertool*"**:
   Esta herramienta viene con la imagen docker de wso2-is y se encarga de cifrar los secretos en nuestros ficheros de configuración.
   Para ello lo primero que debemos hacer es establecer nuestros secretos en el fichero deployment.toml, este sería un ejemplo poco util, pero ilustrativo de como quedaría:

```
[secrets]
super_admin_password = "[{{ .Values.wso2.super_admin_password }}]"
bbdd_pass = "[{{ .Values.wso2.BBDDConfPassword }}]"
```

> Note como los secretos son englobados con "***[ ]***".
> El valor {{ .Values.wso2.super_admin_password }} es parte de una variable de helm, podría ser sustituido para este ejemplo como *admin* o el valor de su usuario.

***Los secretos deben definirse al final del archivo "deployment.toml"***

Posteriormente se asignan a la variable en cuestión de la siguiente forma:

```
# Seteamos el secreto.
[super_admin]
username = "{{ .Values.wso2.super_admin_user }}"
password = "$secret{super_admin_password}"
```

> EL secreto está definido en la etiqueta "secrets" al final del fichero, como se explica anteriormente.

Creamos el archivo "password-tmp" con la password de su almacen de claves principal (por defecto "*wso2carbon*") en la ruta definida en la variable "*PRODUCT_HOME*", en la imagen docker de WSO2-IS es /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-[version de wso2is]/.

Este archivo se eliminará cuando arranque el servidor o el contenedor. Si desea que persista debe guardar el fichero como "password-persist".

> Para SO Windows los nombres de ficheros cambian ligeramente añadiendo la extensión "txt".

El siguiente paso pasa por ejecutar el comando para cifrar todos los secretos definidos en la seccion [secrets] de deployment.toml:

```
sh /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.11.0/bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure -Dpassword={{ .Values.wso2.alias_jks }}
```

El cual dejará los secretos cifrados y preparados para ser leidos en tiempo de ejecución.

> Cuando arranquen el servidor si todo fue correctamente verán una traza como la siguiente , en mi caso se puede ver la variable del ejemplo:

```
ID: [-1234] [2021-06-25 16:38:48,882] []  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Value Target=$secret{super_admin_password} Data={"Claim Value":["ad0e1b3d-4b30-472f-b8c9-c939d15a1273"],"Claim":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:id","Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
```

Un saludo y espero que os valga!. Cualquier aportación adicional será de gran ayuda ya que la documentación sobre el producto en ocasiones no es de mucha ayuda.